# Active Directory Lighweight Directory Service is not available on Windows Server 2008 HPC editon SP1

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008, directoryservices

I am trying to install and configure Active Directory Lightweight Directory Service(ADLDS) on windows Server 2008 HPC edition SP1. But in Server roles i am not seeing any option to enable and install this role.

Is this edition supports this feature ? If so, Is there any way to install ADLDS on the server ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe try from PowerShell (make sure it's admin): `Install-WindowsFeature ADLDS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately HPC is limited in AD support as it was built mainly to support HPC apps. See Server role comaparison below

[image: 2008 Server role comparisons]

Comment: could you please provide me weblink that will explain these role comparison ?